# Is there any formula to copy cells?

Tags: excel

Is there any Excel formula which copies for example all the cells A1:A10 exactly?

I know I can do it with copy paste, but I was wondering if there is any formula.

Thanks!

Comment: Just use equal `=` like in `B1` cell put `=A1` then drag and drop till `B10`.

Comment: Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This little macro will copy contents/formulas exactly, but not formats:

```
Sub KopyKat()
    Range("B1:B10").Formula = Range("A1:A10").Formula
End Sub
```

A *formula* can only return a value to a cell.

Comment: Thank you a lot!.

Comment: Hello can you help me with something? At school I have to use , in formula not ; as I am used to at home.                                                                                                                             Do you know how can I set it to ; ? so the formula SHOULD BE : =IF(AND(C5>1000;IFERROR(FIND("Mondiala";A5);0)) not this : =IF(AND(C5>1000,IFERROR(FIND("Mondiala",A5),0))                                    I mean that ; between 1000 and IFERROR. (thats just an example). Thanks. Sorry if I cant explain good, I am new to Excel. Thanks again.

Comment: @cezar40  You are describing a **Regional Setting** ..................Excel can use either **,** or **;** ..................open a new Question and you may get help....................